# trying to calculate sum of row with dataframe having NA values

Tags: r

I am trying to sum the row of values if any column have values but not working for me like below

```
df=data.frame(
  x3=c(2,NA,3,5,4,6,NA,NA,3,3),
  x4=c(0,NA,NA,6,5,6,NA,0,4,2))

df$summ <- ifelse(is.na(c(df[,"x3"] & df[,"x4"])),NA,rowSums(df[,c("x3","x4")], na.rm=TRUE))
```

the output should be like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
df <- transform(df, summ = ifelse(is.na(x3) & is.na(x4), NA, 
                                  rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)))
df

#   x3 x4 summ
#1   2  0    2
#2  NA NA   NA
#3   3 NA    3
#4   5  6   11
#5   4  5    9
#6   6  6   12
#7  NA NA   NA
#8  NA  0    0
#9   3  4    7
#10  3  2    5
```

In general for any number of columns :

```
cols <- c('x3', 'x4')
df <- transform(df, summ = ifelse(rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) == length(cols), 
                                   NA, rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: It will add a new column `summ` in your original data without changing the original columns.

Comment: so i have many columns likewise so i have to mutate many summ columns in data frame like summ1,summ2......

Comment: for example i have to apply the same for many columns so i have select the columns manually    
df <- transform(df, sum1 = ifelse(is.na("x3") & is.na("x4"), NA, 
                                                rowSums(df[,c("x3","x4")], na.rm = TRUE)))

Comment: this is giving a strange output

Comment: @str_rst This is not how you do it for multiple columns. I have already shown in my post how to do it for multiple columns. Read the answer after `In general for any number of columns :`. Include all the columns that you want to apply this for in `cols <- c('x3', 'x4')` and use the answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!( is.na(x3) & is.na(x4)),summ:=rowSums(.SD, na.rm = T)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below with `rowSums` + `replace`

```
df$summ <- replace(rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE), rowSums(is.na(df)) == 2, NA)
```

which gives

```
> df
   x3 x4 summ
1   2  0    2
2  NA NA   NA
3   3 NA    3
4   5  6   11
5   4  5    9
6   6  6   12
7  NA NA   NA
8  NA  0    0
9   3  4    7
10  3  2    5
```

Comment: replace will  change the original data ...??

Comment: @str_rst No, it doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

This is not much different from already posted answers, however, it contains some useful functions:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Count = ifelse(all(is.na(cur_data())), NA, 
                        sum(c_across(everything()), na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Rowwise: 
      x3    x4 Count
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     2     0     2
 2    NA    NA    NA
 3     3    NA     3
 4     5     6    11
 5     4     5     9
 6     6     6    12
 7    NA    NA    NA
 8    NA     0     0
 9     3     4     7
10     3     2     5
```

Comment: Would you be able to show how this would work for a selected set of columns in a dataframe, as in the selected answer?

Comment: In that case you need to change `cur_data()` in a way that Ronak showed above.